# no render with mat-error, ng-template and *ngTemplateOutlet

Tags: angular, angular-material, ng-template, ng-container

This code is working fine and properly (without ngTemplateOutlet):

```
<mat-form-field [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <input matInput type="text"
        [formControlName]="fControlName"
    >
  <ng-container *ngIf="isShowErrors()" ngProjectAs="mat-error">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let error of showSMErrors" >
      <mat-error>{{ error.message }}</mat-error>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</mat-form-field>
```

But this code isnt working properly(with ngTemplateOutlet), why? (just see the error.message like a normal red color text):

```
<mat-form-field [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <input matInput type="text"
        [formControlName]="fControlName"
    >
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="showErrorsTemplate"></ng-container>
</mat-form-field>

<ng-template #showErrorsTemplate ngProjectAs="mat-error">
  <ng-container *ngIf="isShowErrors()" >
    <ng-container *ngFor="let error of showSMErrors" >
      <mat-error>{{ error.message }}</mat-error>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</ng-template>
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like mentioned here in this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50475917/7741865:):

> The `<mat-error>` elements need to be direct children of `<mat-form-field>` in order to work properly.

So like in that answer, where case being a separate component, it also applies here: Set your container inside the `mat-error` tag and it will work just fine!

```html
<mat-form-field [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <input matInput type="text" [formControlName]="fControlName">
  <mat-error>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="showErrorsTemplate"></ng-container>
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

which then means you don't need to use `mat-error` inside your `ng-template`.

Comment: Disclaimer: I was on the fence of marking this as a duplicate, but I saw it as bit different question than the one linked..

Comment: Its a totally different code what i wanted. Cannot possible to show only mat-errors with template and reuse it.. Thank you the answers!