# For some reason my custom mat-erro is not working. Anyone knows why?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

For some reason the `mat-error` is not working as expected.

I created a custom component that handles my errors. But on rendering it's not working as it should.

That's the page

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <input matInput placeholder="Enter your email" formControlName="ip" required>
  <app-form-field-error [form-control]="resourceForm.get('ip')"></app-form-field-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

That's mine custom component html

```
<mat-error >{{errorMessage}}</mat-error>
```

That's mine custom component ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-field-error',
  templateUrl: './form-field-error.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form-field-error.component.css']
})
export class FormFieldErrorComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input('form-control')
  formControl: FormControl;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  public get errorMessage(): string | null {
    if (this.mustShowErrorMessage()) {
      return this.getErrorMessage();
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }


  private mustShowErrorMessage(): boolean {
    return this.formControl.invalid && this.formControl.touched;
  }

  private getErrorMessage(): string | null {

    if (this.formControl.errors.email) {
      return 'formato de email inválido';
    } else if (this.formControl.errors.minlength) {
      const requiredLength = this.formControl.errors.minlength.requiredLength;
      return `deve ter no mínimo ${requiredLength} caracteres`;
    } else if (this.formControl.errors.maxlength) {
      const requiredLength = this.formControl.errors.maxlength.requiredLength;
      return `deve ter no máximo ${requiredLength} caracteres`;
    }
  }

}
```

Expected : http://prntscr.com/o35s9k

Result : http://prntscr.com/o35shk

Answer (score 0):

I change the first code to:

```
<mat-error >
    <app-form-field-error [form-control]="resourceForm.get('ip')"></app-form-field-error> </mat-error>
```

and changed the app-form-field-error to:

```
<ng-container>{{errorMessage}}</ng-container>
```

Now is working like a charm!

THANKS!

Comment: Yes - mat-error cannot be used in sub-components. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50467206/mat-error-put-to-separate-component-not-rendering-properly/50475917#50475917.